# Is there a mechanism in the human brain that works analog to LSTMs?

Tags: comparison, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, brain, neuroscience

Is there a mechanism in the human brain that works analog to LSTMs? Is there a biological/neuroscientific interpretation of LSTMs and recurrent neural networks? How do long-term and short-term memories work in the brain, on a neuron level?

I would also appreciate links to more in-depth explanations in the literature.